# Marklogic memory usage

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am using Marklogic 8.0-1.1, Windows 7 with 4GB RAM. Marklogic Using more than 90% of Physical memory(System Resource Monitor Commit(KB) 6,890,111 and working Set(KB) 3,601,012). This above scenario is happening every day at random time, during this occurrence i am not able to query or use my system or any other application. I can end this only by stopping the marklogic and Start after few minutes. 
This is not happening when query is executed, and also from the database status page its Not reindexing/refragmenting. 
Please let me know how to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to the latest version of MarkLogic, which is currently 8.0-3.3? I'd start with that. Then start 8.0-3.3 up and go to Groups/Default in the Admin app on port 8001 and see what your caches are configured to - with only 4gb of RAM, those caches should be fairly small - they should add up to no more than 1/3 of 4gb RAM, if my memory serves me correct.